# Pygame download image from a folder

Tags: python, image, pygame, load

Whenever I try to add a picture from a folder in pygame it says no such file or directory even though the same code and folder worked with others
i work with vscode

Answer (score -1):

Are the other files you are talking about in the same folder as the new file ? If the same code worked with the path **`img/some_picture.jpg`** but you moved the new file to a different folder, then it will not see the old path: **`img/some_picture.jpg`**
In this case, copy the folder with pictures to a new folder with nesting.
check if the path is correct and if the code is spelled correctly. If anything, throw off examples and screenshots of the location of the folders